# Dynamically add partial view to page with jquery + Zend Framework

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, partial-views, dynamically-generated

Is it possible to add a partial view to a view with a button? So when you press a button you can load a partial view and send parameters to it.

For example when I want a partial view for a question and everytime I click "Add Question" a partial view adds to my page with different id's .. in my partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of, yes. However you'll need a *direct* URL to this partial view. Which means it probably won't really be a partial.

Normally partials are included server-side and don't have a direct URL. Since this is being called by the browser though, you need to be able to load it directly in your browser via a URL.

Then a simple:

```
 $("#container-div").load("/url/to/your/view/");
```

Will call that URL and stick it in your `<div id="container-div">`.

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how I can send parameters and receive them?

Comment: @nielsv Just like you would do it with any other page. You can do it the ZF way with `/url/to/page/param1/param1Value` or the raw PHP way with `/url/to/page?param1=param1Value` in which case you can receive them server-side via `$_GET`.